# What are the recovery scenario for Selenium Framework?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, java, test-automation-framework

How to handle recovery scenario in my framework. In this framework I want to create some methods which work after catching exception. So that I can easily come back on the normal stage from any of the damaged situation during the  execution of my script?

It is an eCommerce application share some scenario according to application from where i can put my recovery scenarios methods?

Please share some example as well so that I can easily understand

Comment: Hi Shailendra Rathore; sorry but your question is difficult to understand. Can you explain a bit further what you mean?

Comment: Hi @VinceBowdren I want to prepare recovery scenario in my framework. After catching exception how can i recover from that situation during execution.

Comment: Do you have an example of an damaged situation?

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal Damaged situation is anything. It would be any type of exception its not specific.

Comment: I think we do not understand why you want to recover. If a test fails it fails. Why do you want to recover? What is the goal?

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal - We just want to handle Post Recovery. Please have a look this link http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/recovery-scenario-in-selenium/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to verify that if some error happens, you can still use the site afterwards. Because damaged situation = failed test, and problem in your site, and you really should not keep going.

If that's the case, then, when one of your tests fails but another doesn't you can already see that application is back to normal stage, no?

Or you can try running failed tests again, there is some info: [Restart failed test case automatically in testng/selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8713564)

Alternatively you can implement error handling around your selenium methods (pseudo example).

Instead of:

```
driver.FindElement(element).Click();
```

Write recovery scenario:

```
void Recover(){
   do something
}
```

Look for exceptions:

```
void ClickAndRecover(element){
  try { driver.FindElement(element).Click(); }
  catch (couldnt click) { Recover(); }
```

Not for click specifically. But in my opinion it would be a bad practice.